# What is this screening tree, growing in South Australia?

Tags: identification, hedge

Can anyone identify this screening tree/hedge growing in the Adelaide plains, South Australia? Any family or clade suggestions will help!

I'd like to propagate it next to the fences in our own backyard because it looks hardy and demonstrates excellent foliage density for screening.

<sub>(Click on images to enlarge)</sub>
[image: Screener side view]
[image: Screener leaf view]
[image: Screener leaf closeup]

Comment: Gets thin here at 3m (9'10") tall, but the tips are above 3m.

Comment: Do you think it could be a [Syzygium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium) specifically [Lilly Pilly](http://www.loganrivertreefarm.com.au/lilly_pilly.htm)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it a pittosporum - possibly *Pittosporum Screenmaster*? I looked on the web and found a number of pictures of trees looking very much like these trees eg check out [this link](http://www.primeplants.com.au/plants/Hedging-and-Screening-Plants/Pittosporum%20Screenmaster/).

Comment: Verified by specialist at plant nursery. Is most likely the 'Screen Master' cultivar of Pittosporum tenuifolium - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittosporum_tenuifolium